# Sorting arrays numerically in PHP

Tags: php

i have a group of arrays that i need to sort numerically:
example:

```
    $a= array('Adam','maths',3,'physics',5,'sports',6)
    $b= array('Mike','maths',6,'physics',2,'sports',8)
    $c= array('Sam','maths',3,'physics',9,'sports',6)
    $all = array($a,$b,$c)
```

Now i need to sort $all by considering only the numbers. is there an alternative to the function sort? thx

Comment: What would the result look like...?

Comment: normally the result will be $result=array($b,$c,$a)

Comment: @ader277 your expected result still not clear

Comment: Yeah, still not sure what you're sorting by. The sum of all numbers in each array...? The first number in each array...?

Comment: you know it's like when we do in sql SORT BY (maths,physics,sports) then the guy with a better mark in maths come first : it's $b .Because $a and $c have the same marks in maths we order them by using the marks in physics and that is why $c come in second place and $a in last place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a sane array structure:

```
$array = array(
    'Adam' => array('maths' => 3, 'physics' => 5, 'sports' => 6),
    'Mike' => array('maths' => 6, 'physics' => 2, 'sports' => 8),
    'Sam'  => array('maths' => 3, 'physics' => 9, 'sports' => 6)
);
```

Then, do a simple custom sort:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['maths'] != $b['maths']) {
        return $a['maths'] - $b['maths'];
    }
    if ($a['physics'] != $b['physics']) {
        return $a['physics'] - $b['physics'];
    }
    return $a['sports'] - $b['sports'];
});
```

Comment: thx but that is not helping me because the inputs are not mine and the outputs of my function need to respect the same form.

Comment: Well then, you should be able to adapt the above function to your needs. Take the 3rd, 5th 7th etc array index for comparisons instead of `$a['maths']`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function, with `SORT_NUMERIC`

Here's the [demo](http://codepad.org/wvomTCoB).

Comment: sorry i did not formulate my question in a good way. I just edited so you can understand what i meant

Comment: Do you want `$all` to only contain numbers?

Comment: nope i want $all to become $all=array($b,$c,$a)

Comment: What is the sort based on? Looks like you just need a specific format `$b, $c, $a`. Then you just need to use `array_push`, in that order.

Comment: Is this http://codepad.org/zelTc7KD what you're looking for?

Comment: you know it's like when we do in sql SORT BY (maths,physics,sports) then the guy with a better mark in maths come first : it's $b .Because $a and $c have the same marks in maths we order them by using the marks in physics and that is why $c come in second place